# Create a new user using tastypie results in 401

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a user resource like this

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):

  class Meta:
    queryset = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    resource_name = 'user'
    excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
    serializer = CamelCaseJSONSerializer(formats=['json'])
    list_allowed_methods = ['post']
    detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch']
    authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
    models.signals.post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=User)

  def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    try:
      bundle = super(UserResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, **kwargs)
      bundle.obj.set_password(bundle.gata.get('password'))
      bundle.obj.save()
    except IntegrityError:
      raise BadRequest('The username already exists')
    return bundle

  def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
    return object_list.filter(user = request.user)
```

I am using slumber to create a new user with this line of code

```
import slumber
>>> api = slumber.API("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1")
>>> new = api.user.post({"firstName" : "fname", "lastName" : "lname", "username" : "anewuser", "password" : "123456", "email" : "email@email.com"})
```

I get an error which says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/slumber/__init__.py", line 125, in post
    resp = self._request("POST", data=s.dumps(data), params=kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/slumber/__init__.py", line 104, in _request
    raise exceptions.HttpClientError("Client Error %s: %s" % (resp.status_code, url), response=resp, content=resp.content)
slumber.exceptions.HttpClientError: Client Error 401: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/
```

I don't think I should be getting a 401 when creating a new user...

I don't want the API to be open so a list of all the users can be retrived and I only want the logged in user to get their information

What am I doing wrong?

**A better way to do it - Create a new resource which will be used for creating users. This resource can only be called by the superuser**

```
class UserSignUpResource(ModelResource):

  class Meta:
    object_class = User
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    allowed_methods = ['post']
    include_resource_uri = False
    resource_name = 'newuser'
    excludes = ['is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
    serializer = CamelCaseJSONSerializer(formats=['json'])
    authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
    authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
    models.signals.post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=User)

  def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    try:
      bundle = super(UserSignUpResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, **kwargs)
      bundle.obj.set_password(bundle.data.get('password'))
      bundle.obj.save()
    except IntegrityError:
      raise BadRequest('The username already exists')
    return bundle

  def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
    return object_list.filter(id=request.user.id, is_superuser=True)
```

Create a new user with this command

```
curl -v -X POST -d '{"username" : "username", "password" : "123456"}' -H "Authorization: ApiKey superusername:apikey" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/newuser/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a new resource

```
class UserSignUpResource(ModelResource):

  class Meta:
    object_class = User
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    allowed_methods = ['post']
    include_resource_uri = False
    resource_name = 'newuser'
    excludes = ['is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
    serializer = CamelCaseJSONSerializer(formats=['json'])
    authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
    authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
    models.signals.post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=User)

  def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    try:
      bundle = super(UserSignUpResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, **kwargs)
      bundle.obj.set_password(bundle.data.get('password'))
      bundle.obj.save()
    except IntegrityError:
      raise BadRequest('The username already exists')
    return bundle

  def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
    return object_list.filter(id=request.user.id, is_superuser=True)
```